# Como mover todos los archivos de un directorio a determinados directorios dependiendo de la extension

Tags: linux, bash, línea-de-comandos

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme con esto , no me sale nada de lo que hago y no encuentro la forma de hacerlo **es en** **bash shell script en linux**

Comment: Por favor comparte tu código para que algún compañero pueda ayudarte de la mejor manera posible.

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** , te recomiendo que realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi obtengas tu primera medalla, ademas mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para asi poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo mover archivos de un directorio a arrays?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329399/c%c3%b3mo-mover-archivos-de-un-directorio-a-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

Podrias poner las instrucciones de cada extension por separado.

```
//myscript.sh
 mv *.jpg locacion/de/tu/directorio/jpg/
 mv *.html locacion/de/tu/directorio/html/
```